# How to update a Div once from inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php

What i am trying to accomplish is that the PHP checks for the variable of Update that is held in another php document.

upon the change of Update from 'test' to something else it will change what is being displayed in the Div 'text1' which is the Variable Update2

The only part that does not work is the echo'......' command in the PHP script.

I want the script to reload the Div tag but only once , any ideas why it is not working?

Thanks in advance

---

Javascript function for updating Div Tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function UpdateSub1() {
  var url = 'followers.php';           
  $('#text-wrapper1').load(url + ' #text1');
  };
</script>

<?php
include "test.php";
```

PHP Script

```
if($Update == "test"){
    $Update2 = 6;   
}

if($Update != "test"){
    $Update2 = 4 ;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> UpdateSub1(); </script>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Use -> include "test.php"; at the top . NOT after <script>..</script>

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com then how will that function be called before its defined?

Comment: wrap your JS in $(document).ready(function() { ..code here..  });

Comment: So you want proof ? Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/L3gom1u9/

Comment: Still not working with wrapping it in the $(document)..... it goes into the php function but i think its the echo '<script type="text/javascript"> UpdateSub1(); </script>'; that is not working

Comment: I even put a function into the code to run an alert, but that did not run from within the php.